# gcc scanf warning believes float is double

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-warnings, scanf

I have a question regarding a warning message from the gcc compiler. The warning message occurs when an argument of scanf isn't a pointer to the variable that should carry the user input.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    float number;
    scanf("%f", number); /* the value of 'number' is passed, instead of the adress to it */
    return 0;
}
```

gcc will give the following warning message when it compiles the program.

```
scanf-problem.c: In function 'main':
scanf-problem.c:5:5: warning: format '%f' expects argument of type 'float *', but argument 2 has type 'double' [-Wformat=]
     scanf("%f", number);
     ^
```

Like expected gcc wants the second argument of scanf to have the type 'float *' (the pointer to a float). What troubles me is that gcc believes that the second argument have the type 'double', when it actually have the type 'float'.

Which leads me to the question, why do gcc believe the second argument of scanf to be a double, when it actually is a float?

I have made some research on this topic to get an answer, but every answer I find is about how to get rid of the warning (write '&number' instead of 'number').

Comment: It is basically scanf accepts address, like float *, and you have passed number which is 8 bytes, are you on a 64 bits PC?

Comment: That explains a lot. Indeed I am on a 64-bits PC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Which leads me to the question, why do gcc believe the second argument
>   of scanf to be a double, when it actually is a float?

Because `float` is promoted to `double` as specified in C Standard

> 6.5.2.2  Function calls
>
> [#6] ... arguments
>          that have type float are  promoted  to  double.   These  are
>          called  the  default  argument  promotions.
>
> [#7]  ... The  ellipsis  notation  in  a  function  prototype
>          declarator causes argument type conversion to stop after the
>          last  declared  parameter.   The default argument promotions
>          are performed on trailing arguments.

Answer (score 3):

You already know that you are passing wrong thing (as mentioned in comment) to `scanf` So just informing you reason behind the warning is `float` argument that you provide is first promoted to `double`.

Answer (score 3):

Your compiler is right, the argument passed to `scanf` is indeed a `double`: for the `...` part of the argument list a set of default conversions is performed. In particular all `float` arguments are promoted to `double` and this is what `scanf` gets to see.

Answer (score 1):

[Edit]  Other than posting the `scanf()` prototype, I now see the answer echoes @chill.
"imitation is the sincerest form of flattery."

---

Check the prototype for `scanf()`

```
int scanf(const char * restrict format, ...);
```

That `...` means any number of any type of arguments are allowed.  For historic reasons, all FP arguments of *smaller* than `double` are promoted to `double` when passed to such functions.  That why the compiler calls it a `double`.

`char`, `short` are promoted to `int` too.

C11 6.5.2.2 6

" ... integer promotions are performed on each argument, and arguments that
have type float are promoted to double. These are called the default argument
promotions. ... "

Answer (score 1):

The error message was misleading, scanf expect an address to the variable to fill the data back to it and you passed a value, and when scanf lookup that address it finds it to be different than what was suggested in formating "%f"

you can change it to

```
scanf("%f", &number); // &number instead of number
```

and it will work just fine

Comment: The question wasn't about how to solve the warning message. What I questioned was why gcc believes my float is a double in the error printout.

Comment: imagine it like this 
float a;
float * pointerToA = a; // value of a instead of address of a
scanf("%f",pointerToA)
now it will look in the memory for arbitrary index given but the value of a which could be anything